# Matlab ODE45. How to change a function inside it while calling it?

Tags: matlab, loops, ode, numerical-integration

The functions `w_d(Y,T)` and `q(tg,tm)` are being used in a function called by the ODE solver described below:

```
function dPdh=gasstep1(~,P)
global rho_solid W_B S e height_dryer c_a c_b tm_o

dPdh=zeros(size(P));
Y=P(1);tg=P(2);

% Mass Balance
dPdh(1)=rho_solid*(1-e)*S*height_dryer/W_B*w_d(Y,tg);
% Enthalpy balance
dPdh(2)=-rho_solid*(1-e)*S*height_dryer/W_B*(1/(c_b+c_a*Y))...
         *(q(tg,tm_o)+(c_a*(tg-tm_o)*w_d(Y,tg)));

dPdh=[dPdh(1)
      dPdh(2)];

end
```

The ODE solver is called in the following manner:

```
tspan=linspace(0,height_dryer,100);
format long
[h,P]=ode45(@(h,P)gasstep1(h,P),tspan,[Y_o tg_o]);
```

The values from the generated arrays and `P` are used in a `for` loop to compute variables:

```
X1=zeros(1,Nh);Tm=zeros(1,Nh);
X1(1,1)=X_o;Tm(1,1)=tm_o;

for i=1:Nh-1
    % Mass balance
    X1(1,i+1)=X1(1,i)-dt*((P(i+1,1)-P(i,1))/(h(i+1)-h(i)))*(W_B/S)*(1/(rho_solid*(1-e)));
    % Enthalpy balance
    Tm(1,i+1)=Tm(1,i)+dt*(1/(c_s+c_al*X1(1,i)))*(q(((P(i+1,2)+P(i,2))/2),Tm(1,i))-...
              ((c_a-c_al)*(Tm(1,i))+hv(Tm(1,i)))*w_d((P(i+1,1)-P(i,1)),     ((P(i+1,2)+P(i,2))/2)));
end
```

The doubt I have is whether the variables in the function `w_d` and `q` also change when I call the ODE solver in a loop. I found a method to implement the ODE solver in a loop on the mathworks website ([link](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/answers/62168-can-you-use-ode45-in-a-for-loop)). I have found help provided when ODE parameters need to be changed ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680224/matlab-ode45-how-to-change-a-parameter-inside-it-while-calling-it?rq=1)).

I think my final code should look something like:

```
for j=2:Nt
    for i=1:Nh-1
        % compute X1 & Tm
    end
    % change variables in function w_d and q
    % [call the ODE]
end
```

Could anyone please give me an idea on how to start the loop which would help me to complete the code.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. I don't know what you mean by "an idea on how to start the loop." You've posted a lot of specific code that may matter to you, but just ends up confusing and cluttering your fundamental question. I can only suggest that you learn about [function handles](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html) and in particular [parametrizing functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html). You can start by [not using global variables](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/572169/80812) inside of your integration function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links you pointed to should answer your question: you could make w_d and q parameters of the gasstep function, and use the function parameterization as in the second link you posted.

From the code you posteed, I understand that you want `w_d` and `q` to be dependent on `X1` and `Tm`, right? I'm going to assume that's the case. If they depend on other parameters, just use those instead of `X1` and `Tm` in my explanation:
make `gasstep1` dependent on `X1` and `Tm` and pass them along to `w_d` and `q`: your gasstep1 function now has 4 arguments: `gasstep1(h, P, X1, Tm)`, and w_d and q also (`w_d(Y, tg, X1, Tm)` for instance). Then you only need to create gasstep2 as such:

```
gasstep2 = @(h,P) gasstep1(h,P,X1,Tm)
```

and you can call ode45 on `gasstep2`!

Be careful that in your final code, if you write it like you presented above, `X1` and `Tm` are going to depend on P, which needs to be initialized!

Comment: Thank you for your answer/help and I did end up finding the answer to my question in one of the links that I posted.

Comment: @winoi Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer helped solving your issue, please mark it as accepted! Happy coding!

Comment: Hi @Etienne Pellegrini, if I do this, I dont need to use "interpolation" in ODE45, right?