# How can I iterate using ode45?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write some matlab code. Why won't my new variable `w` get accepted so that my function can take another parameter? I want to iterate over the variable that is now 7.8 and use iteration instead.

```
 function dZ=sys(x,Z,w)
    c=@(z)4800 - 20.2090 + (17.3368)*z/1000+ (272.9057)*exp(-z*0.7528/1000); % c(z)
    c=c(2000);
    deg=w;

% Z(1):=z
% Z(2):=u
    dZ=zeros(2,1);    % a column vector
    dZ(1)=Z(2);
    dZ(2)=-(c/cosd(7.8))^2*(((-272.9057*0.7528/1000)*exp(-Z(1)*0.7528/1000)) + 17.3368/1000)/...
        (4800 - 20.2090 + (17.3368)*Z(1)/1000+ (272.9057)*exp(-Z(1)*0.7528/1000))^3;
    end
```

I get an error message when trying to use the new variable in my function that worked before.

```
Error using sys (line 4)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in odearguments (line 88)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 114)
[neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir, y0, f0, odeArgs, odeFcn, ...

Error in underwater (line 2)
[X,Z]=ode45(@sys,x,[2000 tand(7.8)], 7.8);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write the function as follows (although `w` doesn't appear to be used):

```
function dZ=sys(t,Z,w)
    z = 2000;
    c = 4800 - 20.2090 + (17.3368)*z/1000+ (272.9057)*exp(-z*0.7528/1000);
    deg=w; % not used?

    dZ=zeros(2,1);    % a column vector
    dZ(1)=Z(2);
    dZ(2)=-(c/cosd(7.8))^2*(((-272.9057*0.7528/1000)*exp(-Z(1)*0.7528/1000)) + 17.3368/1000)/...
        (4800 - 20.2090 + (17.3368)*Z(1)/1000+ (272.9057)*exp(-Z(1)*0.7528/1000))^3;
end
```

and then call the `ode` solver as follows:

```
[T,Z_sol] = ode45(@(t,Z) sys(t,Z,w),x,[2000 tand(7.8)]);
```

where `w` and `x` are defined in your base or caller workspace.

Answer (score 0):

The ODE solver is expecting a function of two variables.  It is looking for a function in the form of:

```
y' = f(t, y)
```

So, if you are passing @sys to ode45, it must be a function of only two variables.

In the comments below you reference another question.  They use the following call:

```
[t,N] = ode45(@(t,y) rateEquations(t,y,F), timeSpan, initialConditions)
```

Using @(t,y) makes a generic function which is a function of two variables.  In this example the function rateEquations is called with a fixed F value.  So ODE is in fact expecting a function of two variables.  If you have a function of more than two variables you can recast it as a function of two variables by copying the technique used in the example you reference.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how can I use iteration in the function if it can't take another variable? I want to iterate over beta variable that is now 7.8.

Comment: The answer is incorrect, you can pass on additional parameters to the `ode` function, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680224/matlab-ode45-how-to-change-a-parameter-inside-it-while-calling-it

Comment: @am304, I updated my answer with an explanation of the question you referenced.  It is passing a function of two variables, using a technique recasting the original function of 3 variables into a generic function of 2 variables.